# developing django projects using git sub-modules

Tags: python, django, git

I have a DJango project that uses menus as part of the application

For example:

```
MENU:  CUSTOMER   VENDOR   EMPLOYEE
```

I would like each area to be assigned to a developer for creation and modification: one for Customer, one for Vendor, one for Employee.

How could one do this?

My thoughts would be that the DJango project would be as follows:

```
Main (which is the project)

Main

=> CustomerApp

=> VendorApp

=> EmployeeApp
```

Main would be assigned to a Git repository

CustomerApp, VendorApp and EmployeeApp would be assigned to Git Sub-Modules.

The person working on CustomerApp would ~only~ have access to CustomerApp (and not the other areas: EmployeeApp, VendorApp)

One developer could not "step on" or "see" the work of another developer.

Could this be a valid approach?

TIA

Comment: Whether this is a "valid" approach is not the real question here, IMO. You *can* do this. The question is: *should* you do this? Is it guaranteed that a vendor and a customer will never interact (i.e. a model from one app won't need to reference a model from the other)? I once worked on an inventory project, with an inventory app, and other ordering apps, etc. Obviously, the ordering app needed to reference models in the inventory app, so that you knew what could be ordered in the first place. You should consider these situations.

Comment: @ray - thanks for the response. >>> " Obviously, the ordering app needed to reference models in the inventory app, so that you knew what could be ordered in the first place."  - yes, to come about this, it was suggested to have a directory of "models" that all cold access. Inside the "models" directory, there would be a sub-directory for each "app". Sample directories: "db models/app1/models.py", "dbmodels/app2/models.py", etc. All would have access to the "dbmodels" directory (which was also supposed to have a sub-module associated with it )

Comment: @ray - the person over that sub-module would have DB design experience and would essentially act as a DB modeler/administrator

Comment: I once considered using git sub-modules for a project, but I didn't really have a requirement to justify the added complexity. I'd suggest reading the [Git - Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) section of ProGit. It might give you a better idea not only of how to use sub-modules, but also on whether it's even a good idea to use them in your case or not. I don't have all the information you have, and you're in a better position to decide. Therefore, my recommendation is that you get a good handle on the trade-offs and whether it will be helpful to you or not.

Comment: @ray - thanks for the info.

Comment: Also, the idea of defining the models that belong to an app *outside* that app seems to be contrary to the Django practice and what's expected, since apps are supposed to be "self-contained", and removing the models from the apps that "own" them seems to go against this.

Comment: @ray - thanks again for the response. I am kind of new to Django (have worked with Laravel though).  If apps are supposed to be self-contained, then why does the "templates" directory exist at the project level (and not the app level)? In it are the HTML defs, CSS defs, etc. They are not in the same directory as the app.

Comment: I think you should complete the Django tutorials; it will give you a better idea of why some things are the way they are.

Comment: Found this here: http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/   and it most definitely makes more sense than what I have seen in some blogs.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest avoiding git-submodules. They will just make life more difficult for your developers.

Whilst it is try that your developer could end up stepping on each others code, this is exactly what git is supposed to help with. It make resolving conflict easier.

Having said that, having multiple app within a single git repo will also help avoid this.

I would question the need for developers to be isolated from each other - Being able to see each others code helps them learn from each other. I would encourage it rather than try to prevent it.

Use git with pull requests, devs can then review each others code, improving the over all quality. It also helps avoid devs stepping on each others code.

I would also be wary of submodules as they are not kept in sync. So as your developers make changes - you, or whoever is in charge of maintaining and releasing the main git repo needs to ensure all new changes are pulled into the main repo manually. So there is a lot of scope for forgetting.

Comment: thanks for the response. "Use git with pull requests, devs can then review each others code, improving the over all quality. It also helps avoid devs stepping on each others code." - understood. I remember when working at one position. I was not allowed to ask colleagues (or discuss with them) items relating to the job. I was instead required to discuss issues with the lead only. The individual mentioned that this was the way they could evaluate my abilities/background.

Comment: have extended that philosophy to this situation. There will be hiring of developers from different software houses. In order to evaluate the abilities of said developers, the idea was to isolate the code from each one. The development house that produces the more "responsible" code would be awarded with additional work.